# Send Push Notification From Salesforce to Ionic Mobile App

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush, sfdcmobilesdk-android

Is the standard salesforce push notification work for all hybrid platforms?. Do I need to use third party application like one signal or firebase for this?

Comment: We have built custom hybrid mobile app using SFDC Mobile SDK before with Push Notification Support. Check this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/push_using_hybrid.htm

Comment: Are you trying to use the Salesforce Mobile SDK -OR- the Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK?  They are different and their use will be different.